# c# Re-order Icollection<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

sinse it is a read-only property in an object(EF entity), I cant replace it with a new Icollection instance.

I am able to clear the collection and add all reordered item, But I want a better way to do this.

ps: I am trying reordering children of an property after entity object loaded.

update:
finally I decide to create a new object for json response

```
//var result= an EF object
return Ok(new
                    {
                        ID = result.ID, 
                        childs =result.childs.OrderByDescending(q => q.ID)
                    });
```

Comment: Why should ICollection<T> have a order?

Comment: Don't try to sort it it just make a new list and use that where you need it

Comment: `ICollection` could be anything from a `HashSet` to a `LinkedList`, and not all collections would make sense to sort. Without some more details, this is a very difficult question to answer.

Comment: actually I am trying reordering children of an property after entity object loaded. because I get wrong value from .select(s=>new{c=s.children.orderBy(...)})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `ICollection` into the constructor of a `List`, then sort that:

```
var list = new List</* your object type here */>(collection);
list.Sort((a, b) => /* your ordering logic here */);
```

Comment: the ICollection<T> is a property in an object, I could not replace it with another varible.

Comment: @CharlesChou So you need to sort the collection within another object without separating it from said object? That's a sort of detail you should really include in your question post. Any other such details we should know about?

Comment: It is entity object, and I need to reorder its children. seems it is not recommend to modify the children, so I create a new object to store the reordered children.

Comment: @CharlesChou You are correct. If the children are stored in an `ICollection`, then sorting them wouldn't make sense as the specific collection type underlying that interface might not be one where sorting is applicable (such as a dictionary or hash set). In order to sort it, you would need to store the collection's entries into one that you *can* sort, which is what I've done in my answer.